# OpenCV: Do we need to delete CvPoint's and how to do it?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

So we have something like:

```
//...
    for(i=0;i<out->size;i++)
    {
        CvPoint pt1 = { out->values[ i * out->dim + 0 ], out->values[ i * out->dim + 1]};
        CvPoint pt2 = { out->values[ i * out->dim + 2 ], out->values[ i * out->dim + 3 ] };
        cvLine(destination, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(240, 255, 255), 1, CV_AA,0);
    }
//...
```

performed 24 times per second for something like 200 lines. Do we need to delete CvPoint's and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to delete them, the compiler deletes the CvPoint instances automatically for you as they are stored on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to delete pointers, and then only pointers to objects allocated with `new`. Normally, clean up in C++ is automatically handled by destructors (e.g. `CvPoint::~CvPoint`). Therefore `delete` is exceptional outside destructors.